# Basic SQL logic of NOT and NULL values when using =

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from dual where not (1=2 );
```

One row returned.

```
select * from dual where not ( 5=null);
```

No rows returned.

```
select * from dual where not (1=2 and 5=null);
```

Unexpectedly, row returned.

Am I missing something basic how NOT works?
Or how AND works?

Tried in Oracle 11 and 12.

Answer (score 1):

This is all fine.  Almost any operation with `NULL` returns `NULL`, including `=`, `<>`, and `NOT`.

But, let's parse that last `where`:

```
where not (1 = 2 and 5 = null);
```

is the same as:

```
where not (FALSE and NULL)
```

Well, `AND` returns `FALSE` if *any* of the operands are `FALSE` -- even if others are `NULL`.  Look at this another way, whether the `NULL` is "TRUE" or "FALSE", the expression is `FALSE`.

Hence, the result is the same as:

```
where TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I guess my assumption was NULL and FALSE, would return NULL.

Comment: @user2469062 . . . `NULL OR FALSE` returns `NULL`, but `NULL AND FALSE` is well-defined, because of the `FALSE`.

Comment: I thought this was an interesting little topic so [I made an SQLFiddle to show what's legitimate and what isn't](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4bc32/7). I thought others might find it informative.